# Cant change DNS to 1.1.1.1 in Ubuntu

Tags: dns

**Solved, see L.D. James' answer and the comment on it.**

I've seen this being asked in earlier versions of Ubuntu, but with no answer that helped.

I've tried to change my DNS via WiFi-settings as it says on CloudFlares webpage. But after doing it and rebooting, I try and check my DNS with "nslookup www.google.com" and it is still using my old DNS?

What am I doing wrong?

This is my current settings:

**Screenshot #1:**

[image: Screenshot]

**Screenshot #2:**

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu uses the **resolvconf** package for managing the DNS configuration.  It's called during the dhcp assignments.  You can override the router's dns configuration by configuring resolvconf.

Edit the `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` file and place your DNS preferences there, which will take precedence.

Add this line to the `head` file:

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

It'll look like this (`/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`):

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN

nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

You can also place other defaults there.

The other information provided by the router will also show up in the `/etc/resolv.conf` file upon reboot.  The the search order will be your specification.

The `YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN` notice in the `/etc/resolv.conf` is the content of the `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` file which is always loaded upon boot and normal network discovery changes.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77959/discussion-on-answer-by-l-d-james-cant-change-dns-to-1-1-1-1-in-ubuntu).